# Find the closest commit between two git repos that don't share history?

Tags: git

I have two Git repos, they both contain the same codebase but one has been stripped of it's history. Without knowing anything about the source of the second repo beyond a vague date range based on the presence of particular files, how would I automatically scan the history to find the commit in the first repo closest to the state of the second repo?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 2 repos `RepoA` & `RepoB` and `RepoA` happens to be with most history.

Within `RepoA` fetch commit history of `RepoB`

```
git remote add old /path/to/RepoB
git fetch old
```

Now you can use the `log` command to see the commits that are in the master branch of RepoA that are not present in RepoB/master

```
git log old/master..master
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following script when I have access to files, which at some point in the git history was copied. With this script it should be fairly easy to pinpoint relevant commits.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
KNOWN_FILE=$1
KNOWN_SUM=$(cat $KNOWN_FILE | sha1sum)
FILE_REVISION="$2"
shift
shift
SEPARATOR="---\n"
echo "The file $KNOWN_FILE($FILE_REVISION) is located in the following commits"
git log "$@" --pretty=format:'%H' | while read commit ; do
    if [ "${KNOWN_SUM}" == "$(git show $commit:$FILE_REVISION 2>&- | sha1sum)" ]; then
        echo "$commit"
        SEPARATOR="---\n"
    else
        echo -ne "${SEPARATOR}"
        SEPARATOR=""
    fi
done
```

It takes at least two parameters, the first parameter is the file you known exists in the git history of a repository and the second is the relative file path in the git repository. The rest of the parameters is given to *git log*.

example usage

```
$ ~/bin/history_locate.sh ../pom.xml.old pom.xml --all
The file ../pom.xml.old(pom.xml) is located in the following commits
---
7144ad970b1db19356941b97bc72564290403497
---
51c1cacc2b04ebeed47a4b27b9bf8b8301f5fe7c
e69d6f60edbb76ed3f377f2aac5be6289b19eee5
2b0f446fca4dec8d84781877f0b38d020e5ac2af
46d412ff0a95bea1cf340e736f5a87a90f13bedd
---
```